# Child Visibility Affects Parent Visibility

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a weird issue when setting a child container to `visibility: visible` via JavaScript in the `$(document).ready` function.

Here's the problem:

I'm having a parent element, that has bootstraps helperclass `class="d-none"`.
I now want to set the CSS of the child of this element to `visibility: visible`.
The problem is that, as long as the `$(document).ready` function is running, the parent and its child are visible.

This means that some weird stuff is going on, since wrapping a visible element in a hidden element should always show nothing. 
But apparently it does show both the parent and the child.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

TO BE SPECIFIC HERE:

1. I want to call the `$(document).ready` function
2. I don't want to see the child, nor the parent when calling the function, as this following code does also not show the child nor the parent because the parent has "d-none"

```css
.parent{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="parent d-none">
    <div calss="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Why can the parent be seen in the below snippet, when setting the visibility of the child via js?

The parent should still have "d-none", and therefore all its children should also not be visible, or what am I understanding wrong here?

To reproduce this issue, copy the lower code snippet to your answer and hit run a few times, you will see the yellow and red rectangles show up for a short amount of time, before they are actually not visible anymore.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".visi").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

```css
.d-none {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.visi {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class="d-none">
  <div class="visi" style="visibility: visible;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your actual code are you including the bootstrap CSS in the `<head>` section?

Comment: @abney317 yes in the head section

Comment: My only thought here was that potentially the bootstrap CSS hasn't loaded yet, but if you have it in the head then it should work fine.

Comment: I'm not seeing any flickering in Chrome 74 on Windows 10, no matter how many times I run it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start out by saying that I probably do not understand 100% of what you are trying explain. This is what I have gathered please inform me of any differences:

1. Your while loop was an attempt to reveal the divs at a future time.

   - loops are way too fast to be any use as a timer you need `setTimeout()`
   - JavaScript is asynchronous so if you plan to reveal one div and then the next (I'm guessing here because you weren't really specific), you'll get one possibly finishing before another or possibly way later. You can make times synchronous by using `async function` and `await` keyword.

     - asynchronous: A set to start at 2secs and B set to start at 2.5secs they'll both end possibly at the same time.
     - synchronous: A starts at 2secs and ends B stars 2.5secs later.
2. You right to assume that a child is is hidden if the parent is hidden ***except*** if the parent has `visibility:hidden` and a child has `visibility: visible` the parent will remain hidden and the child will be visible.
3. Bootstrap class `.d-none` is entirely different. It is `display:none;` which practically removes the element from all but HTML. With `visibility:hidden` the element still takes space. An element with `display:none` doesn't take up space.

```js
function reveal(selector) {
  $(selector).css('visibility', 'visible')
}

const selectors = ['.child', '.parent'];
const times = [3000, 5500];

async function sync(selectors, times) {
  const showChild = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(reveal(selectors[0])), times[0]);
    });
  }

  const showParent = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(reveal(selectors[1])), times[1]);
    });
  }

  await showChild();
  await showParent();
}

sync(selectors, times);
```

```css
.parent {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a very good summary, of how to use synced functions, thx for that! But my Problem was something else: I found that even tho setting d-none on an element, the element manages to show up just a tiny amount of time, bevore it really "dissapears".  I have now come to the conclusion that this is a firefox "bug".

Comment: Sounds like [FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content)](https://stevesouders.com/hpws/css-fouc.php) or the tag is programatically disappearing. The initial style should be hidden if it isn't. Also be sure to place `<script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Sounds like it, but can't really be the problem... my style is included in the `<head>` section. More specifically, this is something I can only reproduce in firefox, and when I give the parent element an inline css like `style="display: none" the problem completely dissapears. so its a mix of firefox/bootrap helper class issues that i dont fully understand - but whatever -  thx for your nice explanation still - CLOSED

Comment: Trust me you want to load `<script>` as the last thing because they block which means if its placed before your HTML the HTML must wait to be rendered after the `<script>` is finished. Your `<link>` is perfect where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. I fixed some parts.

```js
function myFunction(){

      if (1 === 1) {
        $(".visi").css("visibility", "visible");
        var i = 0;
        while(i < 100){
          console.log(i++);
        }
      } 

    }
```

```css
 
.visi {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-none">

  <div class="visi" style="visibility: hidden;" ></div>
 


</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

you can set the visibility to hidden at the beginning and then set it to visible

Comment: thats not really what I want. my qustion is: why is the parent visible for a short time, even tho it has d-none class, and i only set its child to visibility: hidden. I think it should be hidden at all times in this case.

Comment: Because you are changing it in cc by changing the background color.

Comment: Im not changing the background color of anything

Comment: .d-none {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
} here you are changing it.

Comment: Well that's normal css applied to the class "d-none" not really a change